# How to have different return value to a function in C#

Tags: c#

I have creating a function to run PowerShell scripts and I need a way to have different return value types to it. In my situation is or `Collection<PSObject>` or `Collection<ErrorRecord>`.

I tried to use Tuple, tried Dynamic... is There a better way to do that?

This is my code of using the latest approach: Dynamic.

```
public static dynamic PowerShellLocal(string scriptBlock)
        {
            using (PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                object endResult = null;
                powerShell.AddScript(scriptBlock);
                var results = powerShell.Invoke();
                if (powerShell.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
                {
                    endResult = error;  
                }
                else
                {
                    endResult = result;  
                }
                return endResult;
            }
        }
```

This approach gave me an exception gave me an exception that I cannot enumerate, because then in my code I use for each to iterate through the result. 
Is there a better way doing that?

Comment: can you make it generic?

Comment: How you are going to use this function?

Comment: You want to return either an ErrorRecord or a PSObject, so why not just let the method return an object?
Or create a new type that contains both types and return that.
Or return a PSObject, and add an ErrorRecord out paramater

Comment: In both your `foreach` loops, you are reassigning `endResult` with each iteration, which means only the last value will be assigned to `endResult`.

Comment: @pm100  I thought about Generic, but I don’t know how to do that.  And Fabio this method is in a class and initiating this method is in another class

Comment: reading the code it seems you want to return either an error or a psobject, in that case I would throw the error and declare the function as returning a PSObject

Comment: This sounds line an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/); why do you need “to have different return value types”? How does the calling routine know which type is being returned?

Comment: Every time you come to an idea of using `dynamic`, rethink it, because most probably you are doing something wrong.

Comment: `I don’t know how to do that` What a great day for you!!! A chance to learn something new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option when you want to return multiple types is to wrap them in a class that has properties of the types you want to return.

For example:

```
class PowerShellResult
{
    public List<ErrorRecord> ErrorRecords { get; set; }
    public List<PSObject> Results { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can just return an object of this new type:

```
public static PowerShellResult PowerShellLocal(string scriptBlock)
{
    var result = new PowerShellResult();

    using (PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        powerShell.AddScript(scriptBlock);
        result.Results = powerShell.Invoke().ToList();
        result.ErrorRecords = powerShell.Streams.Error.ToList();
    }

    return result;
}
```

---

Another common option is to return one of the types directly from the method, and have an `out` parameter for the other type.

For example:

```
public static IEnumerable<PSObject> PowerShellLocal(string scriptBlock, 
    out IEnumerable<ErrorRecord> errors)
{
    using (PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        powerShell.AddScript(scriptBlock);
        var results = powerShell.Invoke();
        errors = powerShell.Streams.Error.ToList();
        return results.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, managed to work with out keyword. Works! thank you

Answer (score 0):

#### A good approach

Use a `try`/`catch` approach, where the function returns your `Collection<PSObject>`, and if the script has an error, collect the `ErrorRecords`, and throw either an [`AggregateException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_AggregateException__ctor_System_Exception___), if you can easily convert `ErrorRecord`s to `Exception`s, or write your own custom `Exception` class.  (The latter is almost certainly better unless `ErrorRecord` is a subclass if `Exception`, which, by C# naming convention, it is not.)

```cs
public class PSScriptException : Exception
{
    public PSScriptException(Collection<ErrorRecord> errorRecords)
    {
        this.ErrorRecords = errorRecords;
    }

    public PSScriptException(Collection<ErrorRecord> errorRecords, string message): this(errorRecords)
    {
        this.Message = message;
    }

    Collection<ErrorRecord> ErrorRecords { public get; private set; }
}

// ...

// within some class
public static Collection<PSObject> PowerShellLocal(string scriptBlock)
{
    using (PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        powerShell.AddScript(scriptBlock);
        var results = powerShell.Invoke();
        if (powerShell.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
        {
            throw new PSScriptException(powerShell.Streams.Error.ToList());
        }

        return results.ToList();
    }
}

// ...

void DoScript(string scriptBlock)
{
    try
    {
        Collection<PSObject> results = PowerShellLocal(scriptBlock);
        doTheThing(results);
    }
    catch (PSScriptException scriptEx)
    {
        handleTheErrors(scriptEx);
    }
}
```

---

#### A hacky approach

Preface: I ***do not*** recommend this method, but it does answer the question asked in the simplest way.

You can return `Collection<object>` and then wherever you use the result, check its type.

```cs
Collection<object> myResult = PowerShellLocal(myScript);
if (myResult is Collection<PSObject> myPSObjects) {
    doTheThing(myPSObjects);
}
else
{
   Collection<ErrorRecord> myErrors = myResult as Collection<ErrorRecord>;
   handleTheError(myErrors);
}
```

The reason I don't recommend this is that C# is intentionally a strongly-typed language.  If you do not want to use the `try`/`catch` method, a better approach than this answer was mentioned in @Rafus's answer, using an `out` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

using "object" cuold be a good solution?

```
    public static object PowerShellLocal(string scriptBlock)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for a function API contract without providing context about how this function will be used.
What consumers of the function will do with the result?

For question "How I can return two different types from one function" you already got good answers. But actual question is how much "troubles" those approaches will produce for the consumers of the function.
As a consumer of the function
 - I need provide a variable for every call
 - If I care about errors, every time I call a method, I need check for errors existence
 - If I don't care about possible errors, creation of `out` error variable is useless

Based on the logic function will return only one result, which can be of "Successful" type or of "Error" type.

That is why question "How you are going to use this method?" is very important (which you didn't answer properly).

Just for fun I will speculate, for example you want to save result, to database when result is successful and to "errors" when function failed.

Then I would create an interface to abstract behaviour on the result.

```
public interface ISavePowerShellResult
{
    void Save();
}
```

Then will create implementations of this interface one for Sql database(Successful records) and one for XML file(Errors).

```
public class SaveSuccessfulObjects : ISavePowerShellResult
{
    private IEnumerable<PSObject> _objects;

    public SaveSuccessfulObjects(IEnumerable<PSObject> objects) => _objects = objects;

    public void Save()
    {
        foreach (var psobject in _objects)
        {
            // save to sql database
        }
    }
}

public class SaveErrors : ISavePowerShellResult
{
    private IEnumerable<ErrorRecord> _errors;

    public SaveErrors(IEnumerable<ErrorRecord> errors) => _errors = errors;

    public void Save()
    {
        foreach (var record in _errors)
        {
            // save error to xml file
        }
    }
}
```

Make returned type to be an interface and function to return implementation of this interface.

```
public static ISavePowerShellResult PowerShellLocal(string scriptBlock)
{
    using (PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create())
    {
        powerShell.AddScript(scriptBlock);
        var results = powerShell.Invoke();

        if (powerShell.Streams.Error.Count > 0)
        {
            return new SaveErrors(powerShell.Streams.Error);
        }

        return new SaveSuccessfulObjects(results);
   }
}
```

Then usage of the function will be very simple for the consumer.

```
var script = "Invoke-Something ...";

var result = PowerShellLocal(script);
result.Save();
```

With this approach, adding more functionalities for the function can be much easier, because only you need to do is create new implementation of the interface, without touching the code where function is consumed.

Comment: You are right, didn't mention why I need this. First of all thank you for the example. Basically I have a windows forms application that on a button click returns output to a Textbox. This operation will help me maybe to log?